# crystal reports suppress element based on last item in report

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm creating a sub report and I want lines between the data items like so:

```
  Main report
       sub item 1
       ----------
       sub item 2
       ----------
       sub item 3
       ----------
       sub item 4
       ----------
  /Main report
```

I'd like to make it a little neater by suppressing the line on the last item of the sub report, like so:

```
  Main report
       sub item 1
       ----------
       sub item 2
       ----------
       sub item 3
       ----------
       sub item 4
  /Main report
```

I'd like the ---------- to be suppressed when
      last item in subreport

Any idea what the equation is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the variable named `OnLastRecord`
[here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc/html/topic755.html)

Answer (score 1):

If the items are rows within a single subreport then you can just use the suppression formula: `onlastrecord`